# Delphi - Pos() with boundaries

Tags: delphi, assembly

I'd like to have a Pos() adapted to be used specifying boundaries within the Source string, rather than have it perform the search in the entire data. F.e: NewPos(SubStr, SourceString, Offset, EndingOffset)

It should be a modification of the current ASM FastCode implementation in the latest Delphi XE3, so that it will be faster than a PurePascal implementation (and obviously also faster than using a simple Pos or PosEx). Also, it should work with Unicode strings.

Comment: This is quite a specific requirement. Do you have at least a Pascal implementation? Perhaps that way you can ask in http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Purepascal won't do, too slow. Ideally it should be either a small change to the current XE3 ASM code, or pick the older FastCode routine, make it work for unicode, then do the change over that.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll post the existing code there.

Comment: until you test it you don't know for sure. And while I think you may be right, having a baseline implementation may help others help you.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at [`PosEx`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.StrUtils.PosEx) in the `StrUtils` unit.  That looks like what you're looking for...

Comment: PosEx only takes a starting offset, I need to specify also a limit offset within where Pos should work on.

Comment: Mason, in XE3 the `Posex()` part has been incorporated into the `Pos()` functions in System.pas.